# Treegrid 9.3.11 not loading in chrome 61

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, treegrid

```
 var D = new TDataIO();

    D.Layout.Url = "scripts/treegrid_9_3_11/batch_treegrid_def.xml";

    if (layoutBonus)
    {
        D.Layout.Bonus = layoutBonus;
    }

    D.Data.Url = url;
    D.Debug = 0;
    D.Data.Timeout = 210;
    D.Page.Url = URL_CONTEXT + "LoadPage.action";
    D.Page.Format = "Internal";
    D.Page.Data = "TGData";
    D.Page.Timeout = 120;
    G = TreeGrid(D, "batchGrid");
```

In JSP we are creating a div like this:

```
<s:div id="batchGrid" cssStyle="height:100% width:100%"/>
```

Error:
Too Small Grid

Not sure how this div height is set as 0px?

```
<div id='batchGrid' style='height: 0px; overflow: hidden;'/>
```

batch_treegrid_def.xml cfg

```
   <Cfg id='batchTable' MainCol='Details'
     Sorting='0' Deleting='0' 
     Scrolling='1' ConstHeight='0' ConstWidth='1' MaxHeight='20'
     Paging='3' ChildPaging='3' PageLength='25'  Copying='1'
     RemoveCollapsed='2' 
     CopyFocused='0' 

     NoHScroll='0' Style='Modern' SuppressCfg='1' StandardTip='1'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> To let grid maximize its main tag to window height, on your page there must not be:
>
> a) any parent tag (in hierarchy from grid to ) with overflow set to hidden, auto or scroll.
>
> b) any parent tag (in hierarchy from grid to ) with position:absolute.
>
> c) any tag (except tags included in tag with not visible overflow or absolute position) with height set to percentage (like height:100%).

So basically, you have to define a static height for your div.

Comment: you mean to say `<s:div id="batchGrid" cssStyle="height:100% width:100%"/>` this cssStyle to a static height? If yes then how it will adjust to full window size on different screen sizes.

Comment: We have some grids with MaxHeight='1'. The parent tag has no height define and as you resize your window, the grids get resized.

Comment: Ok, so I will remove the cssstyle height and width to 100% and change maxHeight to 1. One thing is my grid was loading before upgrading to chrome 61

Comment: For this, you might want to contact TreeGrid support directly